# How to organize my js files

Tags: multisite, javascript, directory, file-manager

I'm working on a multisite instalation, that will have several subsites and i'm in doubt about how to organize my js files.

The [WP Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/)

says that js files should go inside the assets folder.

So as each subsite will have different js scripts, i assume its correct to make a .js file for each site.

My question is if its a good idea to make multiple js files per site, since there are some scripts that will run only on specific custom templates. I ask this because if i did this many of my js files would have only one function inside.

The file structure would be something like this:

Root
-assets
--js
---site1js
----script1.js
----script2.js
----script3.js

---site2js
----scripts.js

Does this affect the performance of the site? Or its just a bad pratice and i should put all the scripts together?

Also, does it apply to css as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, combining all of the global scripts will boost performance, but so will enqueueing JS selectively - meaning if a script is only used on one CPT or template, you should only enqueue it there.

Look into conditionally enqueueing JS in your `functions.php`. You can target specific sites by `blog_id` and target specific post types, templates, etc. If some of your JS is very short, you can also add an inline script rather than serving a separate file. For example:

```
function wpse_306134_enqueues() {
    // enqueue the sitewide theme script file
    wp_enqueue_script('wpse-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wpse.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.23', true);
    // enqueue an inline script only on the 'about' page
    // adjust this condition as needed: if is_singular, etc.
    if(is_page('about')) {
        wp_add_inline_script('wpse-scripts', '(function($){jQuery(document).foundation();})(jQuery); jQuery(".gallery-icon a").swipebox();');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_306134_enqueues');
```

Personally, I would put all my JS files in a single folder and name them by `blog_id` if that applies. It may make sense to have a global JS, then site-specific ones, and then these additional inline enqueues for small snippets that don't apply to most URLs.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the wp_add_inline_scripts function, this will solve my organization problem.